# Apache Multiple Subdomain DNS Handling

Tags: apache, dns

I am currently building an application that I will host and will have multi-tenants (SaaS) called over the web, I would like them to be able to have subdomain.theircompany.com be able to point to subdomain.mycompany.com (or if they wish, point a full TLD to a subdomain with me).

The way I have been expecting this to work is to simply have a wildcard 'ServerAlias *.mycompany.com' in my Apache config pointing to my application, which then extracts the host being called...They then redirect via a CNAME entry on their host.

My question is, would this approach allow external subdomains to be pointed to a CNAME URL instead of IP? As this runs on one account on my system, am I able to install an SSL for a single wildcard if that customers wants to be running on SSL?

Any other suggestions/approaches would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CNAME will work for the purposes of naming, but not for the purposes of a wildcard SSL cert.

Specifically, example.theircompany.com can have a CNAME record with a value of example.yourcompany.com.  This will mean that example.theircompany.com will transparently resolve to your site.  In other words, a browser still sees example.theircompany.com, not example.yourcompany.com.

As such, the SSL cert must be for the theircompany.com domain, not the yourcompany.com domain.